# How to get all near by places using latitude longitude in c# Webservices

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

From Mobile (Android) side they are given Input parameters are latitude and longitude based on latitude longitude get all near by places details return back by using c# web services any one have example code please share with me.
Thanks advance

Comment: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: is there any other was to getting surrounding area names

Comment: Have you read that link ? Take a look at json response from google, you can see also names, like : Cafe Abc, Cafe Def,.....

Comment: Yes, i already checking that link and now working on with that only